# Installing z3 on eclipse (pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, z3

Having trouble getting z3 to work on pydev.

After downloading z3, I went to eclipse windows > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreters and then added "z3/bin" to the library

Running Python 2.7.11 and z3 32-bit

When i try to run simple code

```
from z3 import*  

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

print simplify(x + y + 2*x + 3)
```

Get error

```
NameError: name 'Int' is not defined
```

Comment: Z3 has a function called init, but that's not used with a variable/constant name as a parameter. Did you intend to use Int(...)?

Comment: rechecked. yes it should be int. Still get the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **z3** to the **forced builtins** as described in the PyDev manual:

http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

(i.e.: possibly that information is dynamically given, which means you have to ask PyDev to use a shell to dynamically compute it to you -- otherwise, by default PyDev will only try to statically analyze the code).

Comment: So if im following correctly I did: 


Windows > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreters > Forced Builtins Tab > New > typed z3 > apply > ok. 

If so still same error .

Comment: Before going more into what may be wrong in PyDev: is that script working in the command line?

Comment: Can you compare the pythonpath from the command line vs the one in PyDev? i.e.: run at the start of that script: **import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))** and see if there's anything different.

Comment: Can you do: **import z3;print(z3)** on each case and see if it's actually importing the same module? (i.e.: it's possible that you're shadowing that import)

Comment: on eclipse i get: NameError: name 'z3' is not defined. on console I get: <module 'z3' from 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Downloads\z3-4.3.2-x86-win\z3-4.3.2-x86-win\bin\z3.pyc'>